# adding two fragments next to each other

Tags: android, android-fragments

I want to add two fragments next to each other in activity but when i'm trying to do that i get exception :(Fragment1 did not create a view)
what is the wrong in that code .

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fm.beginTransaction();

    // get the display mode
    int displaymode = getResources().getConfiguration().orientation;
    if (displaymode == 1) { // it portrait mode
        Fragment1 f1 = new Fragment1();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.frag_1, f1);
    } else {// its landscape
        Fragment1 f1 = new Fragment1();
        fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.frag_1, f1);
        Fragment2 f2 = new Fragment2();
        fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.frag_2, f2);
    }
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
  }
}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal"    >
<fragment
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/frag_1"
    class="com.example.android.myapplication.Fragment1"/>
<fragment
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/frag_2"
    class="com.example.android.myapplication.Fragment2"/>
```

**fragment1.java**

```
    public class Fragment1 extends Fragment {
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup vg,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_fragment1, vg, false);
}
```

}

**fragment2.java**

```
     public class Fragment2 extends Fragment {
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup vg,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_fragment2, vg, false);
}
```

}

**fragment_fragment1.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:text="I m fragment ONE"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:background="#5eff6a"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

**fragment_fragment2.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:text="I m fragment TWO"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:background="#ff9e5e"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The **problem** is that you are using **match_parent for both fragments**. You should use breakpoints (e.g. values-w600dp/...) with fixed dpis on landscape and  match_parent on portrait.

By the way, I think your issue can resolve with better code using a [master/detail activity](http://mobileappdocs.com/android.html) (using fragments, of course).

Comment: i changed fragment to FrameLayout and set width to 0dp and weight to 1     that solved the problem thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try using FrameLayout instead of fragment in xml.

Comment: when i tried that app didn't crash but only one fragment appear not two fragments

Answer (score 0):

Since you are adding fragments directly in layout, no need to add them in activity.

Answer (score 0):

Android devices exists in a variety of screen sizes and densities.

A panel or pane represents a part of the user interface. The term pane is a general term used to describe the concept that multiple views are combined into one compound view depending on the actual available space.

If not enough space is available only one panel is shown. This is typically called a single-pane layout.

If more space is available, multiple panels can be shown.

this link may help you:http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidFragments/article.html

Answer (score 0):

Use getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

and follow below link, which have a doc provided on android developer site :

```
https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/fragment-ui.html
```